# Internet Explorer 8 takes forever (>1H) to install. What's up?

Tags: windows-vista, installation, internet-explorer-8, 64-bit

I just connected my brand new Vista 64 bits machine to the Internet and downloaded Windows updates to install.

Downloading went fine, but installation seems to be stuck at the first item, "Internet Explorer 8 for Windows Vista for x64 - based Systems". It's been for nearly one hour now in the "Installing update 1 of 44" state.

What's up ? Yet another joke for Microsoft ? Are they trying to set hooks and hooks deep and large in my system so that I can never, ever uninstall IE8 should I want to ? What a bad way to greet "new" customers like me.

More to the point: what should I do, what can I do ?

1. Is there a chance the installation will succeed, and after how much time ? (Google told me other users have had the same problem, but with other MS OSes)
2. Do I dare click "stop installation" if I don't want to wait ? (I want to go out, and I'm afraid my computer may go asleep, because -- other problem -- last time it went to sleep I couldn't wake it up properly)

Answer (score 2):

I probably got my answer, but can't vouch for sure.

I just noticed a new IE7 window titled "Install Windows Internet Explorer 8" with text "Welcome to..." etc. It may have lurked unnoticed for all the time I waited. Clicking on "accept", not much later the installation proceeded to the next updates.

If my problem was only that... the best conclusion is: DOH! ;-)

Comment: yep that would be it :) It is bloody annoying that its a pop-under window - if you don't know to look out for it then you wait a while :)

I've never left it that long yet though =]

Answer (score 0):

Did you download the [offline installer](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/C/F/DCF5DACB-313F-40C6-889C-AD1F8546099D/IE8-WindowsVista-x64-ENU.exe)?

took me about 2 minutes + restart to install IE8 on Vista Home Premium 64-bit